# How can I extend a data structure within a java static method to be lazy?

Tags: java, static, clojure, lazy-evaluation

I am trying to wrap an external library in more idiomatic Clojure. This includes making its data structures lazy. I'd like to get in the `read` static method below and make `FooList` lazy.

I am running into many problems:

1. Java static methods can't be overridden
2. `proxy` only seems to generate instance objects
3. `gen-class` seems to kinda sorta work but I get lost in sea of namespaces, aliases, etc.
4. The method in question calls another static and private method (which I'd like to reuse), making overriding the public method difficult.

What's the best strategy to do this? Is it possible to open up `FooList` and re-implement it as lazy, with the resulting class being available to the rest of my code?

[org.apache.commons.collections.list.LazyList](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/list/LazyList.html) seems appropriate for the task, but I'm not sure how to go about actually being able to use it.

Help?

```
public class Foo {

    public static FooList read(String filename) {
        FooList foos = new FooList(); //FooList extends ArrayList
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

        for (String s = br.readLine(); null != s; s = br.readLine()) {
            Foo f = parseLine(s);
            foos.add(f);
        }

        br.close();
        return foos;
    }

    private static Foo parseLine(String s) {
        //return s as Foo
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Clojure you can just call (seq collection) on any Iterable collection (e.g. your FooList) and get a lazy sequence that traverses the collection. Though the laziness doesn't actually win you much since you have already loaded the full FoolList on the Java side.

If you really want laziness across both Clojure and Java then you could do the following:

- Have your Java function return a custom implementation of
  java.util.Iterator rather than a complete collection. In order
  to get lazy reading, you should ensure that readLine() only gets called once per iteration (either in the next() or hasNext() method). Remember to close() the reader when you reach the end of the file.
- On the Clojure side create the lazy seq with (iterator-seq java-iterator)

If you do this, then your file will be read in and parsed incrementally as the Clojure sequence is consumed.

Answer (score 2):

Might be completely out of your scope, but I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694517/lazy-non-modifiable-list-in-google-collections). So my final choice was to go with `java.lang.Iterable` which, if you think deeper, fits the lazyness criteria exactly. Yes, it does not have some stuff `List` has (e.g. `size()`), but I could afford to sacrifice this for simplicity. Looking back I have never regret I made this choice.

Comment: I do the same ...simply calling `myFileIterator.next()` to get the next line. Wrapping the IO exceptions as RuntimeException or as null return, either way.

Comment: Actually, if I could monkey-patch `FooList`, I would simply implement [clojure.lang.ISeq](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/ISeq.java): it would just mean implementing `first`, `rest`, `more` and `cons`. But thanks for another idea.

Answer (score 1):

Gnerally in Java this is not worth doing as you usually want to read the whole file.  However say you just want to read the header, or the file it too large to read at once you would read just the lines you need.

However as an exercise, the simplest way to change this class is to edit it.  You can get the source for this class (decompiling it if you have to) and add it first in your class path so it is taken as patch to your current system.

Comment: As I said, I am porting the library to idiomatic clojure, in which lazyness is desired. I suppose I could maintain my own patched copy of the library, but I suspect that would give me some grief later on with new versions, etc.

Comment: @Pedro, desired yes, but any solution which requires you to hack an existing library is probably worse.  The best solution is to ask the providers of the library to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create Bar and BarList with the methods and the lazy feature you want to design, delegating to Foo and FooList and then simple use Bar and BarList??

Did i miss the point in your question?

Comment: I'm looking to monkey patch the class in question, not having developer access to the the external library, nor wanting to maintain my patched version of the code.